# Python: Merge lists within tuples OR combining lists within lists within lists without itertools and thus tuple object

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, python-itertools

I have a list which contains tuples containing lists. Like this:

```
my_list = [(
    [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9, A10, A11, A12, A13, A14, A15, A16, A17],
    [B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6],
    [C1, C2, C3, C4, C5]
),
(
    [A1a, A2a, ......],
    [B1a, B2a....],
    [C1a, C2a....,]
), ........ *27]
```

From every tuple I want to combine the items in the first three lists so `A1`...`C5` into a pandas `DataFrame` because I need to do calculations with them. However I have no idea how to make an iteration over this object, (so to for example append the items into a new list) and failed at this.

The reason I obtained `my_list` in manner I did is because I wanted to make a combination of a list of lists. So I wanted to turn `my_previous_list`:

```
my_previous_list = [[[a1a, a2a,..,], [a1b, a2b,...,], [a1c, a2c,...,]],
    [[b1a, b2a,..,], [b1b, b2b,...,], [b1c, b2c,...,]], [[c1a, c2a,..,],
    [c1b, c2b,...,], [c1c, c2c,...,]]]
```

into a new list containging 27 lists (3*3*3) as such:

```
[
[a1a, a2a..., b1a, b2a..., c1a, c2a...,],
[a1a, a2a..., b1a, b2a..., c1b, c2b...,] ,
[a1a, a2a..., b1b, b2b..., c1b, c2b...,],
[a1b, a2b..., b1a, b2a..., c1a, c2a...,] ........ *27]
```

I used:

```
my_list = list(itertools.product(*my_previous_list)
```

to obtain my result.

Does anyone know how either to merge the lists within the tuples and turn them into a dataframe? or how to bypass this problem by using a different approach than the `itertools` approach I took.

Comment: Can you please format your question a little better to be very clear what is the data you have and what is the expected result?

Comment: First thanks to Chris for editing my question. It looks more appropriate now. In regard to @Walter_Ritzel : The data are numerical values which represent bidding values for incremental capacity offers in the reserve capacity market (electricity auction). I need to combine these values with variables in a separate market clearing model which I have designed. Hope this answers your question

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I still do not understand what is your current state and your desired state... Too much ... in the examples. Would be useful to have a short complete example, so we can evaluate what you need. And to the point I'm saying: in your example, although [c1c, c2c,...,] is in your source, it does not appear in your target....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you need:

```
import pprint

my_previous_list = [[['a1a','a2a','a3a'], ['a1b','a2b','a3b'], ['a1c','a2c','a3c']],[['b1a','b2a','b3a'],['b1b','b2b','b3b'],['b1c','b2c','b3c']],[['c1a','c2a','c3a'],['c1b','c2b','c3b'],['c1c','c2c','c3c']]]

print('Original')
pprint.pprint(my_previous_list)

all_lists = []
for a in my_previous_list[0]:
    for b in my_previous_list[1]:
        for c in my_previous_list[2]:
            line = []
            line.append(a + b + c)
            all_lists.append(line)

print('Processed')
pprint.pprint(all_lists)
```

It is not a pythonic code, but that was the only way I could try to understand your problem.

Comment: Despite the perhaps somewhat vague explanation of the problem, I still got the answer which I was looking for. Thanks a lot @Walter_Ritzel, due to your help this student is going to get his Masters degree a little bit quicker

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
def g():
    for t in zip(*my_old_list):
        yield (e for l in t for e in l)
my_new_list = [list(l) for l in g()]
```

See if it works. It can also be written the following way.

```
my_new_list = [[e for l in t for e in l] for t in zip(*my_old_list)]
```

Bdw, always work with iterators instead of lists while working with big calculations. You would never have gotten `my_old_list` had you been using iterators.

Comment: Thanks for your help # C Panda, it wasn't exactly what i needed but still very helpful to help me reach the final solution. You're definately right about circumventing the use of lists by using iterators, but as I am still a beginning programmer, I am not sure how to do that. My goal is actually quite simple but the code I use now is really dirty. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: What you should do depends on the problem at hand. But you could start by replacing the outer `[]` (list comp) with `()` (generator expressions). More you use generators more **declarative** your code becomes, which is a very very good thing in data processing. Declarative code looks like pipelining in unix shell.